# Weird HTML syntax working on codepen but not locally

Tags: html, css

I want to modify this

https://codepen.io/YusukeNakaya/pen/XyOaBj

the html says

```
.night
  - for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    .shooting_star
```

I have never seen this syntax before, and if I use the css from that link in 
and the html in

but only the background renders, not the stars, but no errors are thrown,

Any help appreciated

Comment: The codepen itself tells you it's `Pug`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't HTML. It's Pug.

You can tell because it says so in the link you posted.

[image: Screenshot]

The [Pug website](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) has tools for converting Pug to HTML.